# Creating a git repo to clone from

Tags: git

Essentially I'm looking to use git as a download command.  I have a project on a centralized server and I'd like to set up an easy way download the project. I would assume that I can set up a git repo on the server and then run git clone locally and that will work but my knowledge and understanding of git is severely lacking apparently. Here is what I'm:

in the directory on the server I run:

```
// set up the git repo in directory named test
git init
git add .
git commit -m "add are all the files"
```

then locally I should be able to run `git clone http://path/to/directory/test.git` (according to the specifications of the host)

But this just gives me an empty repo.  I've looked at several tutorials but there seems to be a leap between the intro tutorials and doing what I want to do.  What am I missing?

There seem to be a lot of questions so I created a chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5635/creating-a-git-repo-to-clone-from

Comment: Are there actually any files in that folder?

Comment: yes there are files in the directory.

Comment: So what do you mean by "it gives me an empty repo" then?

Comment: the clone command downloads an empty directory to the local computer.

Comment: what does `git ls-files` or `gitk --all &` show on local computer?

Comment: Please provide the output from the git clone operation. There are a number of reasons why you might end up with an empty directory. However, it should have a .git directory unless the clone operation failed. So, check for that first.

Comment: git clone says 'you appear to have cloned an empty repository'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your server, create a "bare" repo (one without a local working copy)

```
git init . --bare
```

Then on your client, bootstrap your repo, and push it

```
git init .
touch .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "init my repo"
git remote add origin git://my-git-server.example.com/my_repo.git
git push origin master
```

Once you've done that, other clients will be able to do a

```
git clone git://my-git-server.example.com/my_repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTTP server is not configured to understand Git, it’s using the dumb HTTP protocol, and you must run [git update-server-info](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-update-server-info.html) before it will be served.